# Unable to rotate Device(Auto rotate turned on so its preventing the script to change orientation)

Tags: ruby, appium

I have set auto screen rotate to OFF in my android device. But when I run Appium automation, it gets set to ON somehow. Is there a way to prevent Appium from setting auto screen rotate to ON?

@ruby @appium @realdevice

Error:
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Set the orientation, but app refused to rotate. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Set the orientation, but app refused to rotate.